# How to do css animation or margin left to move div little bit to right side and left side

Tags: css

I am trying to move div to right side and left side using scss. when i click on "Show" option.

If i click the "Show", arrow it will be up. in this case, i want to move div.content  little bit  to right side to viewable.

HTML:

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <div class="menu-card">
            <h3 class="menu-card__heading">Page Content</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Again if i click the "Show", arrow it will be down. in this case, i want to move page content (div.content)  little bit  to left side to viewable.

CSS:

```
.content {
min-height: 455px;
}

ul li .arrow:before,
ul li .arrow:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #f6483b;
width: 3px;
height: 9px;
 }
```

I have tried like this, but not working

```
ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ div:focus .content{ 
 animation: moveright 0.5s ease both;
// margin-left:160px;
}
ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ div .content{ 
 animation: moveleft 0.5s ease both;
// margin-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried like this, but not working
>
> ```
> ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ div:focus .content{ 
>  animation: moveright 0.5s ease both;
> // margin-left:160px;
> }
> ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ div .content{ 
>  animation: moveleft 0.5s ease both;
> // margin-left:0px;
> }
> ```

That is not working because `<div class="content">` is not inside a `<div>`, nor is it inside an element that is a sibling of the `<input>`.

`<div class="content">` is a child of `section`, and `section` is a sibling of `<div class="sidebar">` that contains the `<input>`.

Declare the same margin-left for `.content` as you have for `.header-container`.

Use the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class and the general sibling combinator `~` to remove the margin when the input is checked.

```
.content {
  margin-left: 242px;
}

.sidebar:has(input:checked) ~ section .content {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```css
/* Google Font Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  width: 238px;
  background: #121f26;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar.open {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar.open .logo {
  margin-left: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details #btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details #btn {
  text-align: right;
}

.sidebar i {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar li:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.open li .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar input {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar.open input {
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar.open .bx-search:hover {
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .bx-search:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #11101d;
}

.sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #121f26;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.sidebar li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidebar.open li a .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101d;
}

.sidebar li i {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar li.profile {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 78px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.open li.profile {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar li .profile-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidebar .profile #log_out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .profile #log_out {
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  // left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar.open ~ .home-section {
  left: 251px;
  width: calc(100% - 251px);
}

.home-section .text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  /* padding-top: 35px;
   margin-bottom: 50px; */
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.active-nav-item {
  background: #0c7388 !important;

  i,
  .links_name {
    color: white !important;
  }
}

.fa {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.header-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #677e8c;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 242px;
}

.header-name {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.header-icon {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.fa {
  color: #0c7388;
}

/*Banner*/

.banner {
  background-color: #0c7388;
  padding: 26px 30px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  color: #fff;

  .banner__heading {
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    font-family: 'GE Inspira Sans Bold';
    color: #fff;
  }

  .banner__content {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.content {
  min-height: 455px;
}

.card {
  height: 50px;
}

.menu-card {
  background-color: #e2e8ed;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid #dce0e2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 10px #e2e8ed;
  }

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  .menu-card__icon {
    img,
    svg {
      position: absolute;
      width: 43px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    svg {
      margin-bottom: 17px;
      width: 55px;
    }

    background-color: #fff;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 52px;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #ff7517;
  }

  .menu-card__heading {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #0c7388;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.fa {
  color: #0c7388;
  font-size: 45px !important;
}

/*Accordian*/

.accordion-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  width: 231px;
  top: -25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #6c6c6a;
}
div {
  color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  // max-height: 800px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  margin-top: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  perspective: 900;
  padding: 0 20px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 2px 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #dce7eb;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
  border: none;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
ul li:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

ul li .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-6px, 0);
  margin-top: 16px;
  right: 0;
}
ul li .fas {
  color: #f6483b;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li .arrow:before,
ul li .arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6483b;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
}
ul li .arrow:before {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li .arrow:after {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
ul li input[type='checkbox'] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ div {
  margin-top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}

.sidebar:has(input:checked) ~ section .content {
  margin-left:0;
}
.content {
  margin-left:242px;
}

ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .arrow:before {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .arrow:after {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
.transition,
div,
ul li .arrow:before,
ul li .arrow:after {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.flipIn,
h1,
ul li {
  animation: flipdown 0.5s ease both;
}
.no-select,
h2 {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  user-select: none;
}
@keyframes flipdown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotateX(8deg);
  }

  83% {
    transform: rotateX(6deg);
  }

  92% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes moveright {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotateX(8deg);
  }

  83% {
    transform: rotateX(6deg);
  }

  92% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes moveleft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotateX(8deg);
  }

  83% {
    transform: rotateX(6deg);
  }

  92% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="accordion-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <i class="arrow"></i>
        <h2><i class="fas fa-question"></i>Show</h2>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 1</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 2</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 3</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 4</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 5</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 1</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 2</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 3</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 4</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="links_name">List 5</span>
            </li>
            <li>
            <span class="links_name">List 2</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="links_name">List 3</span>
          </li>
          
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="home-section">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header-icon">
      <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header-name">Title</div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <div class="menu-card">
            <h3 class="menu-card__heading">Page Content</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```